# Reading JSON from SDMX API in R

Tags: r

I would greatly appreciate any proposals on how I would read data from https://sdmx.data.unicef.org/ws/public/sdmxapi/rest/data/UNICEF,DM,1.0/all?format=sdmx-json

I have tried the code below but I am not able to move past this

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

res = GET("https://sdmx.data.unicef.org/ws/public/sdmxapi/rest/data/UNICEF,DM,1.0/all?format=sdmx-json")
res
rawToChar(res$content)
data = fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content))
names(data)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some entries about SDMX in the [*Awesome official statistics software*](https://github.com/SNStatComp/awesome-official-statistics-software) list.

Comment: Thanks @Jaap for the link. Sincerely appreciate

Answer (score 0):

```
res = GET("https://sdmx.data.unicef.org/ws/public/sdmxapi/rest/data/UNICEF,DM,1.0/all?format=sdmx-json")
names(res)
 [1] "url"         "status_code" "headers"     "all_headers" "cookies"     "content"     "date"        "times"       "request"     "handle"     
if (res$status_code != 200)  stop("Something went wrong!")
content <- fromJSON(content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8"))
names(content)
[1] "meta" "data"
names(content$data)
[1] "dataSets"  "structure"
names(content$data$dataSets)
[1] "links"  "action" "series"
```

and so on.